# change all view controller background in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on my project app where I want to allow my user to change the background wallpaper to be same on all screens. I have a settings screen where I am adding that. I have added ImageViews to all view controllers and I have some view controllers that have UIscrollview so I added Imageview to slides template. Now my dilemma is how can I allow the user to pick the preview wallpaper so it changes the Imageview image on every view controller. I already created such @IBOutlets as shown below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var slideBackground: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var homeScreenBackground: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var settingsBackground: UIImageView!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options.. what option is best depends on your needs really.

As Woodstock mentioned in his answer, you could use `NotificationCentre`, I wont re-explain that.

Another option would be to store the image name in `UserDefaults` that you are going to use for the background image.

any time you change the background... set the value

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(imageName, forKey "backgroundImageName")
```

Then in each view controller, just load the value on `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
    if let backgroundImageName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "backgroundImageName") {
        self.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: backgroundImageName)
    }
}
```

Both of these options are not very easy to unit test though. You could use Mocks to test it.

A bonus of this method is that it will 'remember' the setting inbetween the user restarting the app.

An example of how you might reduce code repetition using subclassing:

```
class WallpaperedViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy private var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)
        return imageView
    }()

    private func setWallPaperImage() {
        let imageName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "backgroundImageName")

        let image = UIImage(named: imageName!)
        imageView.image = image
        //imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill


        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.setWallPaperImage()
    }
}
```

Then for each ViewController that has this background image wallpaper just extend this class:

```
class SomeViewController: WallpaperedViewController {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will certainly look into Woodstock's recommendation but it will take me sometime as I am a newbie beginner to app development so I have to learn the notification part. But I think you also solved my user defaults question too. so many thanks. also I think subclassing another way to look at too as @khan mentioned. I guess I have to try bunch of things here.

Comment: Yeah you could use subclassing to reduce code repetition, again... depends on your needs

Comment: I've added an example of how you might do it with subclassing.

Comment: I think i am going to try to do the subclassing option. But I have one question though. If I am setting the userdefaults in my settings screen of my app, is there a way to see the results right away. For example I tap on the wallpaper that i want, it will save to user defaults but can it also refresh the view that is active currently to update to new wallpaper. Can this be done with a single line of code like something similar to tableView.reloadData().

Answer (score 2):

You should use the system wide `NotificationCenter`.

Simply put, you can have objects *subscribe* to the default `NotificationCenter` and specify a selector (method) to execute when a notification is posted.

You can also post custom notifications that represent the wallpaper change event.

I have used this in an app I built to achieve a system wide 'dark mode' transition.

**To post:**

```
@objc func postWallpaperChangeNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .wallpaperChanged, object: nil)
}
```

**To subscribe:**

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(someMethodToRunWhenWallpaperChanges(_:)), name: . wallpaperChanged, object: nil)
```

You also need to remove the observer in `deinit()`.

This is approximate code to give you a flavour, any questions hmu.

Comment: ok but this is for notifying the user that the wallpaper has been modified. but what I want is I have a collection view of wallpapers in my settings screen. user picks one of those and it changes the background of all view controllers.

Comment: @ndarji these are notifications to the view controllers so that they can change wallpapers according to that

Comment: btw, you can attach a new background image using `userInfo` along with the notification

Comment: Oh I see now what you mean.

Comment: this requires embedding this code inside every vc and removing the observer in `deinit` which is alot of code  , this is the process of `viewWillAppear` and `setNeedsDisplay`